# Nginx (proxy_pass) + Gunicorn can’t be reached

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I want to run django with gunicorn and nginx as a proxy server on a remote Ubuntu VPS.

The site works with **djangos dev server**:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The site works with **gunicorns server** (even static files don't work):

```
gunicorn my_project.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But with **nginx** on top I get the following error:

> This site can’t be reached ... refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Also both nginx log files `error.log` & `access.log` are empty.

Here is how I configured nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name my_ip_address;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        }
}
```

In this case gunicorn runs with `--bind 127.0.0.1:8001` of course.

Status check (`service nginx status`) returns:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-09-20 07:41:00 UTC; 1min 19s ago
Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Exactly how are you connecting to the site when you use nginx?

Comment: What do you mean? I type my_ip_address into the browser...

Comment: But *what* IP address? Is your browser on the same network as your server? Is either of them behind a NAT router?

Comment: I am using a remote VPS for nginx+gunicorn+django

Answer (score 2):

First, check your configuration with `nginx -t`. The configuration you posted is not valid as a standalone config file, but I assume you are using the common nginx config structure of having a main `nginx.conf` and `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories.

If it does not complain, introduce an error, e.g. by removing a closing bracket, and try again. If it still doesn't complain, your configuration is not being picked up by nginx.

In this case, check if you created a correct symlink from `sites-enabled/your_config` to `sites-available/your_config`.

If that all seems correct:

- check if nginx is actually running: `ps aux | grep nginx`
- check if nginx is listening to port 80: `netstat -tulpen | grep ":80"`
- check firewall rules

Comment: all tests are OK, but `netstat -tulpen | grep ":80"` returns only gunicorn on `127.0.0.1:8001`, however I have configured `listen 80` in nginx as seen above

Comment: Have you verified that nginx is actually running?